# Erro ao realizar pesquisa em formulário com URL Amigável

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho o seguinte `.htaccess` que até agora tem funcionado perfeitamente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^es/guarapari/empresas/([0-9]+)/([[a-z0-9-]+)/?$ empresas.php?id=$1&nome=$2&cidade=100 [NC]  

  RewriteRule ^es/guarapari/empresa/([0-9]+)/([[a-z0-9-]+)/?$ detalhes.php?txt=$1&nome=$2&cidade=100 [NC]

  RewriteRule ^es/guarapari\/?$ cidade.php?cidade=100 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Porém, possuo o seguinte formulário:

```
<form action="pesquisa.php" method="get" name="pesquisarguia">
        <input type="text" name="consultarguia" placeholder="Localizar empresa" required="required" class="frm-campos">
        <input class="inenviar" type="submit" value="Buscar">
        </form>
```

Toda vez que faço uma pesquisa dá **erro 404** devido eu utilizar URL Amigável.

Qual inclusão devo fazer no `.htaccess` para que minha pesquisa funcione?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da mesma forma que você tem regras "RewriteRule" para outrass urls, crie uma (antes de todas) só para pesquisa.

```
RewriteRule ^es/pesquisa\/?$ pesquisa.php [L]
```

Depois lembre-se de atualizar a action para a url amigável.

```
<form action="es/pesquisa" method="get" name="pesquisarguia">
```

Comment: Parece que suas URLs começam com es/ , por isso mantive o formato.